# Excel VBA: error in setting value using find function

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a fairly inexperienced coder and have a small piece of code that is just falling over each time I run it (although I would swear it worked once and has since stopped!)

I am trying to find a value from a cell (which has a formulas to determine which value I need to find) in a range of cells elsewhere in the spreadsheet.

Originally my code was set as follows (when I think it worked) and I am getting an error message saying "Compile error: object required"

I tried to add the word Set in the appropriate place to stop that but then I get a runtime error 91 message saying object variable or with block variable not set.

My sub is in a class module set as option explicit and the code is as follows;

```
Dim StartRow As Integer
Dim EndRow As Integer

Set StartRow = Sheets("CHARTS").Range("T2:T9").Find(What:=Sheets("CHARTS").Range("O14").Value, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole).row
Set EndRow = Sheets("CHARTS").Range("T2:T9").Find(What:=Sheets("CHARTS").Range("O13").Value, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole).row
```

Any help gratefully received, I just can't see where I've gone wrong...!!

Comment: You do not `Set` an Integer.  Remove the words `Set` from each line.

Comment: Thanks Scott - I tried this but then I get the error message saying "compile error: object required"...

Comment: Then the values are not being found in the ranges.  You will need to change the code and test for that before trying to assign the row to the variable.  There is no row for a range that is nothing.

Comment: I'd suggest specifying the rest of the Find parameters in case they are not what you think they are. If the value is definitely physically there, think that must be the problem.

Comment: Ah - thanks Scott.

Comment: I've deleted the set and unhidden the columns that the code is looking at to help see whether the item is in the range etc. Turns out the code works fine without the Set when the columns are visible but has the Compile error when the columns are hidden.